# r read a line with quotation marks from a txt file

Tags: r, readfile, quotation-marks

This might be something easy but I am having issues with it.
I want to read the first line of a long .txt file, the line is like this (but much longer):

```
"15075060" "15085030" "15085040"
```

and i want to save each of this elements as objects in a vector p, so the vector p should be:

```
> p
[1] "15075060" "15085030" "15085040"
```

I use the next code:

```
setwd("location of the file")                     
fileName="name of the file"
con=file(fileName,open="r")  
line=readLines(con)   
txt = line[[1]]
newTxt <- unlist(strsplit(txt, split = " ")) 
nvar = length(newTxt)
for (i in 1:nvar){ 
  p[i]=newTxt[i]
}
```

and what i obtain is:

```
> p
[1] "\""         "15075060\"" "\""         "15085030\"" "\""         "15085040\""
```

there must be a very easy way to do this but i dont know it

Comment: read.table("mytxtfile.txt") works just fine with this sample of data.

Comment: could you dput(txt)?

Comment: thanks @Len , but i dont want to read the whole .txt file, which is very long, i only need to do this with the first line, how could I?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, add `nrows = 1` in the `read.table()` function

Comment: Thanks @Fino  , but if i do that i obtain:  
    > p=dput(txt)
    "\" 15075060\" \" 15085030\" \" 15085040\""   which is not what i want, i dont know why i get it like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
read.table("mytxtfile.txt", nrows = 1)
```